Type for custom lazy Promise.all
I have a LazyPromise object with all method. It works like Promise.all but the promises start the call not on initialization, eg.:
// It started executing as soon as it was declared
const p1 = Promise.all([Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve('foo')])

// It started executing only when `p2.then()` is called
const p2 = LazyPromise.all([() => Promise.resolve(1), () => Promise.resolve('foo')])

this is the implementation
class LazyPromise {
  static all(lazies: Array<() => Promise<any>>){
    return Promise.all(lazies.map(lazy => lazy()));
  }
}

usage
const result = LazyPromise.all([() => Promise.resolve(1), () => Promise.resolve('foo')]).then(result => console.log(result))

I want make the result with correct types.
Now result is a any[] I want: [number, string]
How infer the correct result types?

Have you looked at how the types for Promise.all are declared?

@Bergi all<T>(values: Iterable<T | PromiseLike<T>>): Promise<Awaited<T>[]>; but is totally different implementatio

You really should make LazyPromise an object not a class if you never plan to instantiate it. Or just a plain function instead of a namespace method.

This is just a little bit tricky. You want a generic, but because of the way function types are inferred the most obvious way to do it fails:
class LazyPromise {
  static all<T>(lazies: Array<() => Promise<T>>){
    return Promise.all(lazies.map(lazy => lazy()));
  }
}

const result = LazyPromise.all([
  () => Promise.resolve(1), 
  () => Promise.resolve('foo') // error, expects a number
]).then(result => console.log(result))

The compiler can't or won't infer the union of the return values of the thunks for T. You can work around this by declaring a function constraint instead and extracting the return value's type:
// Little utility helper type
type ExtractPromiseType<T> = T extends Promise<infer R> ? R : never

class LazyPromise {
  static all<F extends () => any>(
    lazies: Array<F>
  ): Promise<Array<ExtractPromiseType<ReturnType<F>>>> {
    return Promise.all(lazies.map(lazy => lazy()));
  }
}

const result = LazyPromise.all([() => Promise.resolve(1), () => Promise.resolve('foo')])
async function foo() {
  const res = await result
  const first = res[0]  // number | string
  const second = res[1] // number | string
}

Note that this does not treat the array as a tuple but rather the way Typescript normally treats heterogeneous arrays, i.e. as a union of the possible types. The function signature is a bit more complex, but it provides enough hints to the compiler to get you what you want.
Playground

If you make it generic in the array, e.g. T extends unknown[], rather than the function, you can get a tuple back. Also note you can get the generic type out of a promise with Awaited.

To answer your second question first, probably? I've been writing that utility helper since well before 4.5 which is when they docs say they added that builtin utility. As for the second, yeah that's probably cleaner.

Respond my self after a bit of deep diving into Promise.all typescript definition. The final trick is this:
class LazyPromise {
    
    all<T>(values: [() => Promise<T>]): Promise<T[]>;
    all<T1, T2>(values: [() => Promise<T1>, () => Promise<T2>]): Promise<[T1, T2]>;
    all<T1, T2, T3>(values: [() => Promise<T1>, () => Promise<T2>, () => Promise<T3>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3]>;
    all<T1, T2, T3, T4>(values: [() => Promise<T1>, () => Promise<T2>, () => Promise<T3>, () => Promise<T4>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4]>;
    all<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(values: [() => Promise<T1>, () => Promise<T2>, () => Promise<T3>, () => Promise<T4>, () => Promise<T5>]): Promise<[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]>;
    async all<T>(values: ReadonlyArray<() => Promise<T>>): Promise<ReadonlyArray<Awaited<T>>> {
        return Promise.all(values.map((value) => value()));
    }
}

not beautiful, but works
const result = LazyPromise.all([
  () => Promise.resolve(1), 
  () => Promise.resolve('foo')
]) // result is [number, string]

